# How to call and get result of scalar valued function using entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using **Entity Framework 6.0**.

I am having scalar valued function in **SQL Server** signatured as

```
fn_CartAmount(@CartId bigint) RETURNS decimal(18,2)
```

I want to call this function from **Entity Framework** and get its result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
    public decimal GetCartAmount(int cartId)
    {

        var returnCode = new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

        object[] parameters =
        {
            new SqlParameter(@"CartId", SqlDbType.BigInt) {Value = cartId}
            , returnCode
        };

        string command = string.Format("exec @ReturnCode = dbo.fn_CartAmount @CartId");
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, parameters);


        return (decimal)returnCode.Value;
    }
```